# What's the meaning of a formula in MatrixCookbook?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I'm learning the derivatives of matrices and vectors. In *Matrix Cookbook* Chapter 2(page 7), there is a formula as follows:
$$\frac{\partial{X_{kl}}}{\partial{X_{ij}}}=\delta_{ik}\delta_{lj}$$

The formula was given without explaining the meaning of notations $\delta_{ik}$ and $\delta_{lj}$.I can't get the meaning of this formula, wish someone could explain it for me.

P.S. the [link](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) to the book.

Comment: Thanks for the link. *Cookbook* looks like a handy reference. :)

Comment: Does the book begin with "Before cooking up a nice matrix, first enslave the human race and use them as a power source ..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol $\delta_{ij}$ is called Kronecker delta, it is used to denote the components of the identity matrix. That is:

- $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$;
- $\delta_{ij}=0$ if $i\ne j$.

You can write the identity matrix as the matrix of components $(\delta_{ij})$, can you see why?

Now, since a coordinate is independent from the other coordinates, the derivative of $x_i$ with respect to $x_j$ is exactly $\delta_{ij}$. Because $\partial x_i/\partial x_i$ is obviously 1, and $\partial x_i/\partial x_j=0$ for $i \ne j$. (Alternatively, the derivative of the identity map is the identity matrix.)

The formula:
$$
\frac{\partial X_{kl}}{\partial X_{ij}} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{lj}
$$

is exactly the same, where instead of the components of a vector, you take the components of a matrix. The expression is $1$ if and only if $i=k$ and $l=j$, and it is zero otherwise. Meaning: a component only depends on itself, not on the other components.